# Google apps script - Make a single copy of spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, backup

The below code allow me to make a copy (backup) of my spreadsheet every day at 7pm.
However when I check in the morning my folder, I have around 20 copies of it. I would like to make only 1 copy.

How can I change that?

See below my code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
// 18 April 2018
// Google Apps Script to make copies of Google Sheet in specified destination folder

var RUNLOOP = true;

function createTriggers() {
    var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,                                            
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY];
    for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("makeCopy")
               .timeBased().onWeekDay(days[i])
               .atHour(19).create();
      killTrigger();// delete the trigger
   }
}


function makeCopy() {
  for (i=0; i<1; i++){ //to make only one copy

// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date 
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");

// gets the name of the original file and appends the word "copy" followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Backup " + formattedDate;

// gets the destination folder by their ID. with your folder's ID that you can get by opening the folder in Google Drive and checking the URL in the browser's address bar
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1NMA8nNIr2ZLZKm1PkKolORhyjLk3xKdx");

// gets the current Google Sheet file
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())

// makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
file.makeCopy(name, destination);

  }
}

function killTrigger(){
  var trigger = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()[0];
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
}
```

Comment: From where createTriggers method is getting called? Can you put that code as well?

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi This is my full code. I don't have anything else. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are recreating triggers with out deleting them,

Here's the code to achieve your requirement,

```
 var RUNLOOP = true;

function createTriggers() {
    killTrigger();  // Delete any previous triggers.
    var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,                                            
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY];
    for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("makeCopy")
               .timeBased().onWeekDay(days[i])
               .atHour(19).create();
   }  
}


function makeCopy() {  
// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date 
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");

// gets the name of the original file and appends the word "copy" followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Backup " + formattedDate;

// gets the destination folder by their ID. with your folder's ID that you can get by opening the folder in Google Drive and checking the URL in the browser's address bar
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxyyy-zzz");

// gets the current Google Sheet file
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())

// makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
file.makeCopy(name, destination);  
}

function killTrigger(){
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();  
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  } 
}
```

First run `killTrigger()` function once, this will delete all your previous triggers. Now run `createTriggers()` method once as well. This will create 5 triggers for you (1 for every weekday). It will run on 19Hours and call `makeCopy()` method. And that's it.

Comment: Hi Darpan, thank you very much. I have edited my code and will let you know tomorrow if it worked. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Hi Darpan, I have just checked and it did not work. The trigger has not saved any copies this time.

Comment: Hi Darpan, I went to a solution a bit easier and posted my new code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092617/google-apps-script-copy-rows-and-paste-values-to-another-sheet because obviously I still need help :D. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I did some research on this, we no need to call trigger methods google app script itself offering to set triggers as we like for that function, below is an example: Goto to Edit-->Current triggers--->set triggers--> then you will get below screenshot

[image: Screenshot for trigger setting]

Comment: This method does not provide enough Flexibility, like it does not provide you option to run on Weekday only, which is ask in the question

Comment: My trigger works fine for the backup, my only issue to tell the program to make only one copy and not several like the system is currently doing.

Comment: From where createTriggers method is getting called? Can you put that code as well? Also you should delete all your triggers in killTrigger method.Currently you are deleting first trigger only.