# Copy rows and paste values to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I have a unique Google Sheets document with the below code that allows me to:

- copy new rows from source in sheet `MEL Micro Set Up` to `Backup Set Up`
- copy new rows from source in sheet `MEL Micro Confirmation` to `Backup Confirmation`.

All works fine except when I delete rows from both source files it will delete rows from the backup files.

How can we avoid that?

```js
function Copy() {
 var sourceSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17ekZcvPQYrcX1ny-RtPQczEfbmd1JZUkRVx6N7qTtCA').getSheetByName('MEL Micro Set Up');
 var range1 = sourceSheet1.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet1.getLastRow(), sourceSheet1.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation();
 var sourceSheetValues1 = sourceSheet1.getRange(range1).getValues();
 var destinationSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17ekZcvPQYrcX1ny-RtPQczEfbmd1JZUkRVx6N7qTtCA').getSheetByName('Backup Set Up');
 destinationSheet1.getRange(range1).setValues(sourceSheetValues1);

 var sourceSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17ekZcvPQYrcX1ny-RtPQczEfbmd1JZUkRVx6N7qTtCA').getSheetByName('MEL Micro Confirmation');
 var range2 = sourceSheet2.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet2.getLastRow(), sourceSheet2.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation();
 var sourceSheetValues2 = sourceSheet2.getRange(range2).getValues();
 var destinationSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17ekZcvPQYrcX1ny-RtPQczEfbmd1JZUkRVx6N7qTtCA').getSheetByName('Backup Confirmation');
 destinationSheet2.getRange(range2).setValues(sourceSheetValues2);

if (sourceSheet1.getName() !== 'MEL Micro Set Up' || range1.columnStart !== 11 || range1.value !== 0 ) return;
destinationSheet1.getSheetByName('Backup Set Up')
    .appendRow(sourceSheet1.range.offset(0, -3, 1, 11)
        .getValues()[0]);
sheet.deleteRow(sourceSheet1.range.rowStart);

if (sourceSheet2.getName() !== 'MEL Micro Confirmation' || range2.columnStart !== 11 || range2.value !== 0 ) return;
destinationSheet2.getSheetByName('Backup Confirmation')
                 .appendRow(sourceSheet2.range.offset(0, -3, 1, 11)
                                        .getValues()[0]);
sheet.deleteRow(sourceSheet2.range.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: I don't know appscript but I would recommend to separated copy from delete methods. Are changes saved automatically? Perhaps you are deleting before saving.

Comment: Hi Luis, rows are added to back up sheets as soon as there is new entry on source files ('MEL micro set up' and 'MEL micro confirm'). My issue is that when I delete a row on the source file, for example 'MEL micro set up', this row will also be deleted from the backup file. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Again, I would move delete operations to another method, even as a good design practice ;).